# How to exclude lead slash from Spring Web wildcard path variable?

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-webflux

I have this wildcard mapping for `name` variable:

```java
@GetMapping("/{id}/{*name}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getObject(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable String name) {
...
}
```

if I try to execute some request like this:

`localhost:8080/1/test/test.txt`

my variables are: `1`, `/test/test.txt`, but I want `name` as `test/test.txt` without "/".

The question is: how to exclude slash from variable using wildcard mapping (maybe using regular expressions or something)?

Comment: I would not like to use `name = name.substring(1)`

Comment: Try to do {name:.*}